# Windows 10 Environment Path Variables Missing after reboot

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, environment-variables, reboot

I've run into a strange problem in that I've set Path variables in Windows, after a reboot they disappear until I go look at the Environment variable settings.

I can restore them by simply doing:

`System Properties` => `[Environment Variables]` => `[OK]`

...then they are set again!

Note: If I type `[SET]`, I can see them in my `Path`

#### Example:

I have an addition to my path which points to:
`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts`

In ^^that^^ dir I have a file `myscript.ps1`.

If I open PowerShell after booting up, I can type "my `[TAB]`" and it will not find the script.

After Opening the Environment Variables Dialog and selecting `[OK]`, restart PowerShell, I can do the same "my `[TAB]`" and autofill "myscript.ps1" without any issue.

#### Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: I have the same problem, I add a environment variable for the user, reboot, and then the environment variable is gone. I need to manually add the variable again in System Properties => Environment Variables. I have no clue what causes this behavior, it used to work just fine.

Comment: By chance do you have that set as the only value in the section "User variables for x" (where x = user name)? Because in that case it ought to be ";%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts" (w/out quotes"). Beyond that I'd guess that you have a syntax error somewhere in the variable.

Comment: Thanks BrianC and @JosefZ I moved the vairable from "System Variables" to "User variables from X" then validated it with script posted int he answer. Saw that a path to "C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\"... failed to validate. Removed it. Now all paths work after a reboot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This isn't a real answer** (too long and too complex for a comment). **I will delete it** if it proves false way.

Please use the following naive script to check whether your `path` setting is formally valid:

```
### Windows path validity check ###
Function myTest-Path {
Param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [string] $PathString='' )
    if ( '' -eq $PathString ) 
    { 
        '!empty' 
    } else {
        if ( $PathString -match '%' ) { 
            $PathString = (. cmd /c "echo($PathString")
        }
        if ( Test-Path -Path $PathString -IsValid) {
                [string] (Test-Path (Join-Path -ChildPath '' -Path $PathString))
            } else { '!wrong' }
    }
}

Write-Host '### Windows path validity check ###' -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host 'checking $env:Path split' -ForegroundColor Yellow

$aux = $env:Path -replace ';$'        # remove trailing semicolon
$aux -split ";" | 
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            check = '$env:Path';
            valid = myTest-Path -PathString "$_";
            path  = "$_"
        }
    }

Write-Host 'checking HKCU:\Environment\ Path split' -ForegroundColor Yellow
if ( (Get-Item 'HKCU:\Environment\').GetValue('Path') ) {
    $aux = ([Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser.
        OpenSubKey("Environment")).
            GetValue("Path",$False, 
                [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::
                    DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames) -replace ';$'
    $aux -split ";" | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            check = 'HKCU:Path';
            valid = myTest-Path -PathString "$_";
            path  = "$_"
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host 'HKCU:\Environment\ Path does not exist' -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
Write-Host 'checking HKLM:\SYSTEM\…\Environment\ Path split' -ForegroundColor Yellow
$aux = ([Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.
    OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment")).
        GetValue("Path",$False, 
            [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::
                DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames) -replace ';$'
$aux -split ";" | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            check = 'HKLM:Path';
            valid = myTest-Path -PathString "$_";
            path  = "$_"
        }
    }

Write-Host 'checking $env:Path duplicates' -ForegroundColor Yellow
$auxArr = $env:Path.split( ";", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries )
for ($i = 0; $i -le $auxArr.Count; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j -le $auxArr.Count -1; $j++) {
        try {
            if ( (Join-Path -ChildPath '' -Path $auxArr[$j] -ErrorAction Stop) -eq 
                 (Join-Path -ChildPath '' -Path $auxArr[$i] -ErrorAction Stop) )   {
                 Write-Host $('{0,4} {1,4} "{2}"' -f $i, $j, $auxArr[$i]) -ForegroundColor Cyan
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    check = 'duplicate';
                    valid = "$i×$j";
                    path  = $auxArr[$i]
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Host "$i $j invalid folder name in `$env:Path" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host "$i`: [$($auxArr[$i])]" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host "$j`: [$($auxArr[$j])]" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: script updated:

- handles possible empty items correctly (I met weird `;;` in `$env:Path`), and
- returns an array of `PSCustomObject`s for better (potential) consecutive manipulation.

Comment: Thanks @BrianC and JosefZ I moved the vairable from "System Variables" to "User variables from X" then validated it with script posted int he answer. Saw that a path to "C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\"... failed to validate. Removed it. Now all paths work after a reboot!